# check user online if user has internet connection without firebase

Tags: java, android

I want to make an application in which if the user is connected to the internet it must show as an online user on other devices without using firebase. what should be an appropriate way for that?

Comment: This...is really broad for SO... please make a proper research before aksing

Answer (score 1):

What about sending a "message" when you open the connection so the status will be set to "ONLINE" and when the app lose the connection or has been destroyed or go onPause send another message that will say to the server that the user is gone "OFFLINE".

Or you just can send a package from the server to the client every X seconds to check if the device is connected, if it's not responding just set his status to "OFFLINE"